# How can I get the contents of a document and upload to a Mysql blob field using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload, blob

When I run this code, and $testpage is an alphameric string, it is uploaded perfectly.  However, when $testpage is defined using file_get_contents(...), it does not upload at all.

```
<?
...
...

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");


$testpage = file_get_contents('http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php');

$testpage = mysql_real_escape_string($testpage);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO theTable(Description,Document) VALUES('PHP Webpage test','$testpage')");
mysql_close;   
?>
```

I understood from the PHP docs that file_get_contents(...) was the preferred way to convert files into a string that could be stored in a binary field.  I am aware that there are some more security issues that I will have to deal with but first I just want to be able to do the raw upload and proceed from there.  Is there any reason why this should not work and if so, what is the best way to do this?  Or am I just missing something?

Thanks!

R

Comment: You're not even wrapping the string in quotes.

Comment: I tried with quotes and without... still no success

Comment: Put your string in quotes and escape it. That page contains plenty of apostrophes and quotes that need to be properly escaped to work in a query.

Comment: First of all enable error reporting. And check [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: Why are you storing a string as a `blog`? Why not just `text`?

Comment: He'll probably need to store arbitrary data, not just printable text.

Comment: yeah, I need to store arbitrary data.  I have edited the code as you guys have suggested, by adding escape string and quote marks and it still does not work... See my edits.

Comment: @Rossi: Please review your edits, this does not look valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape the string.

```
$testpage = file_get_contents(..);
$testpage = mysql_real_escape_string($testpage);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO theTable(Description,Document) VALUES('PHP Webpage test','$testpage')");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried this and it still does not work... see my edits.

Comment: @Rossi, is that a typo in your code in `$testpageFinal = "'%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($testpage);` ? That's not what my code does.

Comment: You are correct!  The whole %s thing I written before you posted and I thought it was kind of the same but it was not... and your code works perfectly!  Thank you so much, @Dogbert!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `stream_get_contents` instead of `file_get_contents` if you would like to actually request for a webpage and save it in MySQL:

```
<?php
if ($stream = fopen('http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php', 'r')) {
    // get the entire page
    $webpage = stream_get_contents($stream);

    fclose($stream);
}
...
...
```

I think you can just alter the fopen and point it to your uploaded document (or file):

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

$stream = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
// continue with the above code...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've got it now but I will look into the stream to see the advantages.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why is `stream_get_contents` better than `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 1):

I would really look into getting yourself a wrapper class for your database queries. There's a great one that I use at http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-database/.

Using that wrapper, the query would simply be:

```
$db->insert('theTable', array(
    'description' => $msg,
    'document' => $testpage
));
```

As the wrapper already escapes strings automatically, you reduce code while retaining security and functionality.

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out - that seems like a good idea!  Thanks